# Mac OS X application to sync a folder to another disk in real time

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard

Do you guys know any software that can reproduce the entire tree of directories under a certain directory to another disk and keep it update in real-time on Mac OS X?

A kind of mirror RAID, but instead of mirroring the whole disk I need to mirror just all directories inside one specific directory. As a mirror, it must update in real-time, I mean, as files are dropped, modified or created.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do what you want.

http://www.apaulodesign.com/widgets/data-vu.php

Comment: @Mike You're welcome. Although I personally use Dropbox. (https://www.dropbox.com/referrals/NTEwNjgyODk)

Answer (score 1):

Synk 7 does this. I haven't tried it, but have used Synk 6 (and 5) in the past with some success.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able accomplish something like this using Folder Actions with Applescript/Automator.

Try this Automator Action:
http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/automator/backupfolder.html

Save it as a plug-in and attach it to the folder. This article explains the process:
"Fixing Automator Workflow Folder Action Plug-Ins in Leopard" at Peachpit (I can't post more than one link as a new user so you'll have to Google it).

Comment: will this sync folders inside folders? suppose I install this folder action on a folder named "myFiles". Inside this folder I have another one called "images". If I create an image inside "images" will it sync?

Answer (score 0):

If you're OK to spend a few bucks there is [ChronoSync](http://www.econtechnologies.com/pages/cs/chrono_overview.html). It has a neat GUI, and was impressed when I tested it. However I'm not sure about real-time sync (it does scheduled sync, of course).

I stumbled upon [this page](http://www.takecontrolbooks.com/resources/0014/other.html) listing backup software, and specifying the real-time detection the following softwares rise:

- [Memeo Backup](http://www.memeo.com/lifeagent.php)
- [QRecall](http://www.qrecall.com/)
- [Synchronize Pro](http://www.qdea.com/synchronize_pro_x_features.html)

I'll be glad to hear from your tests!